# Write a program that takes a positive number and outputs it as binary

Tags: binary, modello

Write a program that takes in a positive integer as input, and outputs
a string of 1's and 0's representing the integer in binary. Example output: 5 is 101 binary. When the value is 0 or less, output Bye, bye.

I am new to programming and taking my first class learning Python. I am trying to write a program for binary numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
x = int(input("Enter a positive integer to convert to binary (0 or less to QUIT):"))
string = ""

while x >= 0:
    print(x%2, end='')
   x = x//2
while x <= 0:
    print("Bye, bye")
```

I am unsure how to have it output is as binary and not just the number. I also can't figure out how to get the program to run without glitching including 10 with the 0. I want it to print Bye bye for 0 and numbers less than zero while still outputting the correct binary form for 10, etc. Keep in mind that I am a beginner so the code probably isn't perfect.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

In python you can use the "bin()" method.

```
binary_output = bin(x)[2:]
```

The [2:] is to remove the 0b prefix.

If you want to use the while loop, you can use the bitwise operator "&" to extract the lsb and concatenate it with the Output string while x is positive :

```
x = int(input("Enter a positive integer to convert to binary (0 or less to QUIT):: "))
Output = ""
if x <= 0:
    Output = "Bye Bye"
else:
    while x > 0:
    # Extract the lsb using the bitwise and operator "&" and concatenate the output value with the extracted bit 
        bit = x & 1
        Output = str(bit) + Output

        # Right-shift x by 1 bit
        x >>= 1

print(Output)
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that when I was doing further research, but I can't use it in this code I'm supposed to use while loops.

Comment: I get your point, I have made some modification on my answer I hope this can help.